# Problems with login/quiz database tables

Tags: php, sql

To start out, I have a website with a database. I have 2 tables (more, but those are irrelevant) one called user, other called users. I have a quiz setup to work with users, and my regular login setup with the table user.  I decided to move the quiz data (results, scores, etc) saved to the user that was logged on at the time. When I setup the quiz data to the login's database, I got this:

```
Details

Type: PDOException Code: 42S22 Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'on clause' File: /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php Line: 413 Trace

#0 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php(413): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php(1605): ORM::_execute('SELECT * FROM `...', Array, 'default')
#2 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php(650): ORM->_run()
#3 /home/sparkedu/public_html/SimpleQuiz/Utils/LeaderBoard.php(12): ORM->find_array()
#4 /home/sparkedu/public_html/SimpleQuiz/Utils/Quiz.php(193): SimpleQuiz\Utils\LeaderBoard->getMembers('6')
#5 /home/sparkedu/public_html/routes/public.php(54): SimpleQuiz\Utils\Quiz->populateUsers()
#6 [internal function]: {closure}('6')
#7 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(441): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1314): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#9 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#10 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#11 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#12 /home/sparkedu/public_html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1261): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#13 /home/sparkedu/public_html/public/index.php(64): Slim\Slim->run()
#14 {main}
```

I tried creating extra columns so it would keep the login with the results (same row) but It would say unknown column, and then I would have to delete that column to fix it. Any Suggestions?

Comment: There's a faulty join condition, but we can't help without seeing the query that was attempted. What ORM is this? What framework?

Comment: Does your `users` table have `id` column?

Comment: Michael Berkowski > I used Bootstrap & PhP
PM 77;1 > It has a id_user column, but no id column.